# Error in TF 2.3. when mixing eager and non-eager Keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm having this issue when trying to fit a model in Tenserlfow 2.3, are there any workarounds or solutions to the problem? this error occurs also when i try to predict some records using TensorFlow Neural Network models. I hope someone expert in Tensorflow can find out what is wrong!

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

DO_BUG = True

inputs = tf.keras.Input((1,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
model0 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

if DO_BUG:
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        inputs = tf.keras.Input((1,))
        outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
        model1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model0.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.SGD(0.1), loss=tf.losses.mse)
model0.fit(np.zeros((4, 1)), np.zeros((4, 10)))
```

Logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../tmp.py", line 15, in <module>
    model0.fit(np.zeros((4, 1)), np.zeros((4, 10)))
  File "...\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 807, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "...\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 666, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "...\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 189, in model_iteration
    f = _make_execution_function(model, mode)
  File "...\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 557, in _make_execution_function
    return model._make_execution_function(mode)
  File "...\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 2072, in _make_execution_function
    self._make_train_function()
  File "...\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_v1.py", line 2021, in _make_train_function
    **self._function_kwargs)
  File "...\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3933, in function
    'eager execution. You passed: %s' % (updates,))
ValueError: `updates` argument is not supported during eager execution. You passed: [<tf.Operation 'training/SGD/SGD/AssignAddVariableOp' type=AssignAddVariableOp>]
```

Comment: Whats the version of the tensorflow you are using ? I think using `tf.Graph().as_default()` is not supported in tf-2.x versions. Any specific reason you are using this ?

Answer (score 0):

The below code works without error. Any specific reason to use commented part below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

DO_BUG = True

inputs = tf.keras.Input((1,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
model0 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
"""
if DO_BUG:
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        inputs = tf.keras.Input((1,))
        outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
        model1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
"""
model0.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.SGD(0.1), loss=tf.losses.mse)
model0.fit(np.zeros((4, 1)), np.zeros((4, 10)))
```